# Yum installation failes in RHEL 8 EC2 instance

Tags: ansible

Hi I am new to ansible and running into this issue.  So need some expert's help.

I installed ansible on AWS with RHEL 8 as OS.  The instructions are available at the following link.
https://medium.com/@sumitnair89/how-to-install-ansible-on-rhel-8-f2c9d7c5dc8a

Then I created a   playbook   to install Apache on the  control node. However the installtion fails with following message.
TASK [Testing] *****************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "dnf install -y python3-dnf", "msg": "Could not import the dnf python module using /usr/bin/python3.8 (3.8.0 (default, Mar  9 2020, 18:02:46) [GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)]). Please install `python3-dnf` package or ensure you have specified the correct ansible_python_interpreter.", "rc": 0, "results": [], "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "Last metadata expiration check: 1:26:50 ago on Fri 08 May 2020 03:38:55 AM UTC.\nPackage python3-dnf-4.2.17-6.el8.noarch is already installed.\nDependencies resolved.\nNothing to do.\nComplete!\n", "stdout_lines": ["Last metadata expiration check: 1:26:50 ago on Fri 08 May 2020 03:38:55 AM UTC.", "Package python3-dnf-4.2.17-6.el8.noarch is already installed.", "Dependencies resolved.", "Nothing to do.", "Complete!"]}

### My playbook content is below.

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:

  - name: Testing
    become: yes
    become_user: root
    yum:
    name: httpd
    state: latest
    Btw I have installed ansible as a unix user called ansadmin.   Can anyone help me please with this issue?

Comment: Here is my playbook content.

Comment: Can you edit the contents of the question and post yml and output as a code? It will be more readable.

Comment: and, are you sure you have followed all the steps mentioned in the blog? Specifically Python 3.8 and pip installation? Because that is the error. Python and pip are needed for Ansible and in your case, since Ansible couldn't find the required modules.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was setting `ansible_python_interpreter` to `/usr/libexec/platform-python` as described here https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1670188